# Is there some way to insert custom archive loop to any theme from plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm coding plugin that create custom post type with custom fields. Now I need to build custom archive/category/tag templates which should contain custom fields.

The problem is that I couldn't insert template part inside archive loop from plugin.

Is there some hook to insert custom loop inside activated theme? Something like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'change_content_in_single_post');
```

Now I'm using this hook:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'change_whole_cpt_archive_template' );
```

... but when I use `template_include` hook it changes whole template and I need to do something like `the_content` filter. That hook get template of current theme and replace standart content template with my custom template - make it part of activated theme. It makes my CPT single page template compatible with any wp theme. Now I need to replace standart archive loop with my custom loop. For example: on archive page show posts without images... It must be something that replace result of standard `get_template_part()` function with custom template from plugin. That's what I`m searching for...

Anyway, maybe you know some better ways to make plugin (archive template) compatible with wp themes?

Huge thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you need to introduce some logic to only run on your cpt archive page.

```
 add_filter( 'template_include', 'change_all_archive_template' );

 function change_all_archive_template($template){

      if ( is_post_type_archive('cptname') ) {
          $template= 'find the template!';
          //if( file_exists ) --> look in theme 1st??
          //else --> load from plugin..
      }

    return $template;

 }
```

There are quite a few plugins that use this technique to look in the active theme 1st and if not found, find the file in your plugin.

Comment: Huge thanks for your answer!!! But... this hook changes whole archive page template and I need to load only custom list (loop)  inside archive template of activated theme.

Comment: you need to explain this a bit better! The question suggests your are creating a custom post type. This will use the archive.php template unless there is an archive.cptname.php file in your theme. The function above allows you to create a template in your plugin and call that?

Comment: When I use `template_include` hook it changes whole template. But I need to do something like `the_content` filter. That hook get template of current theme and replace standart content template with my custom template. It makes my CPT single page template compatible with any wp theme. Now I need to replace standart archive loop with my custom loop. For example: on archive page show posts without Images... It must be something that replace result of standard `get_template_part()` function with custom template from plugin. That's what I`m searching for...

Comment: theres no filter for that, the archive template code varies widely. The content exists because its saved in the db, the archive template pulls content as needed, e.g. the_title, etc. Best option is to create a custom template, get_header() etc will return the same header etc. But as stated earlier, if a theme user is not happy with your template, they can overwrite it. If its for personal use, just copy the standard template and modify as you wish and place it in the plugin file. Honestly, the alternative is to parse the file and there could be anything in there!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in woocommerce plugin files. 
So... the best way to build custom archive template from plugin is to use `template_include` hook and in custom template file set header and footer from activated theme:

```
<?php get_header();

// custom archive loop

get_footer(); ?>
```

To make it more compatible with any wp themes use stanard wordpress and bootstrap classes.